# Collection.sort using anonymous class Comparator

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, comparator, anonymous-class

I did not find needed information, so I decided to create a new question.

I have a little test app where I want to sort my Map by Values. But I can't understand why I can't do it in the following way:

```
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.Comparator;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    public class Test {

    public int test(int [] array) {

        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(1,4);
        map.put(2,3);
        map.put(5,1);
        map.put(7,0);
        map.put(4,4);
        map.put(9,1);

        Collections.sort(map.entrySet(), new Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> t, Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> t1) {
                return t.getValue().compareTo(t1.getValue());
            }
        });


        for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()){
            sum += entry.getValue();
        }

        return sum;
    }

}
```

and Main class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test test = new Test();
        System.out.println(test.test(arr));
    }
}
```

This app shoud return 14 in this case. But I have this message on 
*Collections.sort(...)* part:

> sort (java.util.List, java.util.Comparator) in Collections cannot be applied to
>   (java.util.Set>,
>   anonymous
>   java.util.Comparator>)
>      reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that
>   Set> conforms to List

but if I change it to *Collections.min(...)* or *Collections.max(...)*:

```
Collections.min(map.entrySet(), new Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> t, Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> t1) {
                return t.getValue().compareTo(t1.getValue());
            }
        });
```

there will be no issues.

Comment: `Collections.sort` accepts a `List`. A `Set` is not a `List`.

Comment: `Collections.sort` takes a `List`, you are giving it a `Set`. The error message is pretty clear. Use a `TreeMap` if you want to sort a map.

Comment: Since all you need is the sum of the values, you don't need to sort them int his case.  I assume this is not the real use case however, in your real use case you should be able to avoid having to sort the Map by value (esp as you can't do this)

Answer (score 1):

Java Map can't be sorted by value. But you can create a list from `Map.entrySet()` or maybe you don't need a collection at all.

Using List and Comparator.

```
List<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Using Stream

```
map.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue))
        //do something here
```